# Binomial summations

Tags: binomial-coefficients

[image]

The given answer is zero. I tried adjusting the 
coefficients, changing to binomial co-efficients.
Like $99C_r$but still the inside terms, i am not able 
to adjust.

Comment: $$\sum_{r=0}^{99}\binom{99}r(99-r)^{50}(-1)^r=-\sum_{r=0}^{99}\binom{99}{99-r}r^{50}(-1)^r =-\sum_{r=0}^{99}\binom{99}rr^{50}(-1)^r$$

Comment: so after this step we can directly say it is zero? by using that since expansion of $(1+x)^n$ , if we go on differentiating and mulitply by x , 50 times, and each term on left will have 1+ x so at x=-1 it becomes zero

Comment: Don't think so. This much I could simplify

Answer (score 3):

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{99^{50}}&\color{blue}{-99\cdot98^{50}+\frac{99\cdot98}{1\cdot 2}\cdot97^{50}
> -\cdots+99}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{98}\binom{99}{j}(-1)^j(99-j)^{50}\tag{1}\\
> &=-\sum_{j=0}^{99}\binom{99}{j}(-1)^jj^{50}\tag{2}\\
> &=-\sum_{j=0}^{99}\binom{99}{j}(-1)^j50![z^{50}]e^{jz}\tag{3}\\
> &=-50![z^{50}]\sum_{j=0}^{99}\binom{99}{j}\left(-e^z\right)^j\tag{4}\\
> &=-50![z^{50}](1-e^z)^{99}\tag{5}\\
> &=-50![z^{50}]\left(1-\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots\right)\right)^{99}\tag{6}\\
> &=50![z^{50}]\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\cdots\right)^{99}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the expression using sigma notation and binomial coefficients.
- In (2) we add $0$ by setting the upper limit to $99$ and change the order of the sum $j\to 99-j$.
- In (3) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series and we note that
  $$j^n=n![z^n]e^{jz}=n![z^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(jz)^{k}}{k!}$$
- In (4) we do some rearrangements as preparation for the next step.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we expand the exponential series to better see what's going on.
- In (7) we simplify the expression and observe that the series starts with powers in $z\geq 99$, so that the coefficient of $z^{50}$ is zero.